# Android: How to set prefered keyboard view mode from IME

Tags: android, landscape, ime, android-input-method, android-inputtype

I am developing an android [IME](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html#InputMethodLifecycle) and I want my keyboard to work only "pan and scan" and "resize" mode, not in "fullscreen" (as explained [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.hu/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html)) or at least request to prefer the "resize" mode. I know that there is a way to set this from EditText but how can I request it **from the IME**? Is there a method that I can call on `onStartInputView` event? Or **how the android system decide which mode will the IME use**?

In one of the note applications in landscape mode the default IME don't use the fullscreen mode, but mine is, so there should be something just I can't find it :S. Maybe it checks the height of the keyboard? If yes how? I would appreciate any ideas, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote an IME one year ago and also considered that if my keyboard should run in screen mode in landscape on a tablet.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onEvaluateFullscreenMode()). Override the `onEvaluateFullscreenMode` callback in the `InputMethodService` class and return whatever you want.

I don't have a try, but this should work.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it in an hour!